# Monero transaction from kraken to bitfinex stucks in status confidential transaction

Tags: exchange, confidential-transactions

My Monero transaction sucks since 2 months and I have no idea how to get my coins back. Bitfinex support does not answer and according to kraken support moneros were send successfully. Find my transaction info below:

https://moneroblocks.info/search/97a4b71c59c6305ad27ec33242ed3e6cce8408bfb5e554a9a3e9897c82ddc380

Is there a way using the monero-gui?

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 3):

If you sent to an address owned by someone else (Bitfinex), then you cannot use a wallet to recover the funds.  It is the responsibility of the address owner (the exchange, Bitfinex) to credit you with those funds, as long as you can prove that they were sent by you or on your behalf.